# Java DateFormat/SimpleDateFormat with Locale (show just day in month and month)

Tags: java, date, format, locale

I have a multicultural application, the project uses Java 7. I need to show the date, but the day in month and month only. So for example in `Locale.UK` today's date looks like: 24/01, but in `Locale.US` like: 1/24. How to achieve this in Java 7? I tried to use `DateFormat.getDateInstance(dateFormat, locale)`, but in this case I can use just predefined date formats, for example `DateFormat.SHORT`, `DateFormat.DEFAULT` etc. there is no predefined format just with the day in month and month only. Next I tried to use SimpleDateFormat with locale, but this is not working as I wonder, it just translates some text according to the locale. Here is my sample code:

```
DateFormat dfuk = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.UK);
DateFormat dfus = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.US);
System.out.println(dfuk.format(new Date()));  // 24/01/17
System.out.println(dfus.format(new Date()));  // 1/24/17
SimpleDateFormat sdfuk = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM", Locale.UK);
SimpleDateFormat sdfus = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM", Locale.US);
System.out.println(sdfuk.format(new Date()));  // 24/01
System.out.println(sdfus.format(new Date()));  // 24/01
```

I expected last line to print 01/24 (or 1/24). How to achieve this?

Comment: You third last line about `sdfus` says `SimpleDateFormat sdfus = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM", Locale.US);` -- Did you mean to say `MM/dd` instead?

Comment: Yes it can be, but in case you said I have to write additional condition which will verify actual locale, and choose appropriate format (dd/MM or MM/dd) I wish to find Java library built-in solution for my problem.

Comment: The `getDateInstance()` method takes an argument for `style`.  The shortest style seems to be `DateFormat.SHORT`.  You can argue that perhaps they should provide one that is even shorter (`DateFormat.SHORTER` perhaps?)  c.f. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance(int)

Comment: My lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) offers the class [net.time4j.xml.AnnualDate](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/xml/AnnualDate.html) with support for four format styles in about ~ 80 locales. The version line v3.x would be runnable on Java-6 or 7, the newer versions v4.x on Java-8. If you still miss any locale then just open an issue on the tracker of Time4J. The current i18n-data are based on unicode-cldr-version v30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your third last line to

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfus = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd", Locale.US);
```

**Overcoming the shortcoming of what standard Java offers:**

The `getDateInstance()` method takes an argument for `style`. The shortest style seems to be `DateFormat.SHORT`. You can argue that perhaps they should provide one that is even shorter (`DateFormat.SHORTER` perhaps?) c.f.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance(int)

Before that happen, you can build an enum of pattern for the shorter style.  Below is an example:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

enum PatternShorter { // or PatternMonthDayOnly
    MM_SLASH_DD     ("MM/dd")
    , DD_SLASH_MM   ("dd/MM")
    ;
    private String pattern;

    public String getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    private PatternShorter(String pattern) {
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public static PatternShorter getDefault() { return DD_SLASH_MM; }
}

public class DateFormatEx {
    private static Map<Locale, PatternShorter> patternShorter = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        patternShorter.put(Locale.UK, PatternShorter.DD_SLASH_MM);
        patternShorter.put(Locale.UK, PatternShorter.MM_SLASH_DD);
        // any locale not listed here will get the default pattern
    }

    private static String getPattern (Locale locale) {      
        if (patternShorter.get(locale)!=null) {
            return patternShorter.get(locale).getPattern();
        } else {
            return PatternShorter.getDefault().getPattern();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Locale> listOfLocale = Arrays.asList(Locale.UK, Locale.US, Locale.FRENCH);
        for (Locale locale : listOfLocale) {
            SimpleDateFormat fmt 
            = new SimpleDateFormat(getPattern(locale), locale);
            System.out.format("for locale %s the shorter date/month display is: %s%n"
                    , locale.toString()
                    , fmt.format(new Date()));  
        }
    }

}
```

The output would be:

```
for locale en_GB the shorter date/month display is: 01/24
for locale en_US the shorter date/month display is: 24/01
for locale fr the shorter date/month display is: 24/01
```

Comment: This is okay, but we have like ~80 locales, in case you said I have to write additional condition which will verify actual locale, and choose appropriate format (dd/MM or MM/dd) I wish to find Java library built-in solution for my problem.

Comment: @bladekp -- I have updated answer and added explanation on how to overcome the shortcoming of what standard Java offers

Answer (score 2):

Your code was throwing the same format because both **DateFormat** were constructed with the same pattern and that is not correct..

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfuk = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM", Locale.UK);
SimpleDateFormat sdfus = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM", Locale.US);
```

You will need the local if you have a String that is going to be converted to date... for the parsing you are trying to do (string -> Date) only the pattern is ok...

**Example**

```
DateFormat sdfuk = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
DateFormat sdfus = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/d");
System.out.println(sdfuk.format(new Date())); // 24/01
System.out.println(sdfus.format(new Date())); // 01/24
```

Comment: This is okay, but we have like ~80 locales, in case you said I have to write additional condition which will verify actual locale, and choose appropriate format (dd/MM or MM/dd) I wish to find Java library built-in solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up modifying the localized format string provided by `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT)`, removing the year part from the format:

```
DateFormat shortDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
String shortPattern = ((SimpleDateFormat) shortDateFormat).toLocalizedPattern();
String shorterPattern = shortPattern.replaceAll("[/\\- ]*[yY]+[^a-zA-Z]*", "");
DateFormat shorterDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(shorterPattern);
```

I skimmed through all 734 locales provided by my system, and the generated date patterns look good for all of them, as far as I can tell.

Some examples comparing the original short pattern to the modified shorter one:

```
         short      shorter
en_US    M/d/yy     M/d
en_GB    dd/MM/y    dd/MM
de_DE    dd.MM.yy   dd.MM.
fr_FR    dd/MM/y    dd/MM
nl_NL    dd-MM-y    dd-MM
ja_JP    y/MM/dd    MM/dd
```

Comment: Works without API34 deprecated Date()

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
MonthDay.from( 
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) 
).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd" ) )
```

> 01/24

## `MonthDay`

There's a class for that: [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html).

The `MonthDay` represents the combination of a month and day-of-month.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.of( Month.JANUARY , 24 );
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes.

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat`, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The `MonthDay` class is part of the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. Much of java.time is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 (see below).

## ISO 8601

> md.toString(): --01-24

The `toString` method generates a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `MonthDay` class can also parse such strings.

## Current date

You want the month-day of the current date. For the current date we will use the `LocalDate` class. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

### Time zone

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Be clear that `Locale` has *nothing* to do with time zones. A `Locale` only applies to the format of text when generating strings, but is separate and distinct from time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

Now extract a `MonthDay` object.

```
MonthDay md = MonthDay.from( today );
```

> today.toString(): 2017-01-25
>
> md.toString(): --01-25

## Other formats

You can generate strings in other formats.

The java.time classes can automatically localize some date-time values by `Locale`. Unfortunately, this does not apply to `MonthDay`. For `MonthDay` you must explicitly specify the desired format in a `DateTimeFormatter` object when you want something other than the standard ISO 8601 format. By the way, I encourage you to **stick with the standard format whenever possible**, especially for exchanging data. You might even consider training your users to accept this format. The standard format is unambiguous, whereas your UK-US formats (dd/MM, MM/dd) can be entirely ambiguous such as 01/02 being either January 2nd or February 1st.

[`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such. Generally, I advise always specifying a `Locale` for your `DateTimeFormatter` rather than relying implicitly on the JVM’s current default `Locale`. But I do not see any way the `Locale` would affect the output of this particular format. So I omit the `Locale` in this example.

```
DateTimeFormatter fUS = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd" );
DateTimeFormatter fUK = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM" );

String output = md.format( fUS );
```

## Live code

See this example [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/HTZbqW).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I think this misses the point of the question.  OP wanted a way to retrieve the "shortest" date format for a locale - that is, MM/d for Locale.US, d/MM for Locale.UK, and whatever format is appropriate for any other Locale, such as dd.MM for Germany.  I don't think it's possible.  But what you've answered is a different question entirely.